# ios SWIFT - how to enable horizontal scrolling on UITextField and disable truncate "..." when text is longer than field width

Tags: ios, swift, scroll, uitextfield

I am very new to swift and stucking to this 2 problems for 3 days.

First, i have a text field and display long number, 
very long than field width.
at one position,  the number is truncated, for example as below

"999,999,999,999,999,9..."

i want it to display the last number and shift previous number to the left.

Second,  i want to make text field scrollable. but can't find how to do. most search result is solution in objective-c.

Could you help enlighten me how to achieve?

thanks,
karamat

Answer (score -2):

Simple answer is by setting the content size more than the screen width

```
ScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake("Declare width here","And Height Here")
```

and please check under Attribute Inspector that **Scrolling Enable** is Ticked Mark .

Second answer

adjust the font size to fit width to the label

```
 label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
```

or set it from the attribute Inspector -> Minimum font size -> Adjust to fit